# java LocalDateTime to date Date JavaScript

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

y have this json from api rest

```
{"id":14,"fecha":"2017-12-26T00:00:00","consulta":"we","metodo":"metodo 23","estado":true,"resultado":"{null}","coordenadas":"20.12122, 12.9888","radioIssi":1,"radioDescripcion":"Radio Movil","radioResponsable":"Ninguno","radioMunicipio":"Municipio 2","radioCorporacion":"Corporacion 2"}
```

But field "fecha" on angular show this error: "fecha":"2017-12-26T00:00:00"

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Invalid Date' for pipe 't'
```

Im trying this

```
<td>{{consultaPlaca.fecha | date:'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'}}</td>
```

But not work

Comment: Your format is invalid, but it's irrelevant. Impossible to reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/4aMA2wT6C4nHewygnoIy?p=preview. So you're probably not passing what you claim you're passing to the pipe. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as I just did. BTW, the message complains about the pipe 't'. Not about the pipe 'DateTime'.

Comment: the field fecha is LocalDateTime

Comment: That is irrelevant. What matters is what the actual JavaScript string you're passing, to which pipe, in which version of Angular.

Comment: i solved usind this:

const entity: ConsultaPlaca = Object.assign(new ConsultaPlaca(), json);
        console.log(entity.fecha);
        entity.fechaTransient = new JhiDateUtils().toDate(entity.fecha);
        console.log(entity.fechaTransient);

im using Angular 4, and in datatable i using this code
<td>{{consultaPlaca.fechaTransient | date:'yyyy-MM-dd T HH:mm:ss'}}</td>